# How to prefix Business Partners using CVI?

Tags: abap, s4hana, badi

I would like to conduct a CVI conversation. Vendor to business partner should have the same number. Customer to business partner should also have the same number but with prefix 'xx' at the beginning.

Example:
Vendor 1234 -> BP 1234

Customer 1234 -> BP **xx**1234

can this only be realized with customizing or do you have to implement this in some badi? if so, which badi should be extended? can I implement this in CVI_CUSTOM_MAPPER?

Comment: I create a BAdi Implementation for CVI_CUSTOM_MAPPER and I deactivate the standard one CVI_MAP_LEGAL_ENTITY. But wehn I debug this it will never get into my implementation. Whta did I did wrong?

Comment: Now I get into my own BAdI Implementation. Changes must be made in Customizing. SPRO -> Cross-Application Compunents -> Master Data Synchronisation -> Custom/Vendor Integration -> Business Partner Settings -> Business Add-Ins (BAdIs) -> BAdI: Data Assignment BP <-> Customer/Vendor/Contact Person -> deactivate the standard one and activate you own BAdI Implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve like this Vendor 1234 -> BP 1234 and Customer 1234 -> BP xx1234, you can make use of BAdI (Business Add-In).

However this can be done through customizing, but you're looking for specific number formats so implementing it in BAdI, CVI_CUSTOM_MAPPER, gives you more flexibility and control.

Great, you've created a BAdI implementation for CVI_CUSTOM_MAPPER. If your implementation is not being triggered, ensure that it is activated and correctly registered in your system and check if there are any conditions or configurations in your implementation that might prevent it from being executed.

To activate your own BAdI implementation, go to SPRO -> Cross-Application Components -> Master Data Synchronization -> Custom/Vendor Integration -> Business Partner Settings -> Business Add-Ins (BAdIs). There, deactivate the standard BAdI CVI_MAP_LEGAL_ENTITY and activate your own implementation.

If you're still having trouble, you can debug your BAdI implementation to resolve it.

Good luck.

Comment: I thought the way back would also be possible with the same BAdI. But unfortunately this is not the case. Which BAdI can be used to receive the synchronization from BP -> Customer?

Comment: According to this Blog: https://community.sap.com/t5/enterprise-resource-planning-blogs-by-sap/sap-s-4hana-business-partner-influence-customer-number/bc-p/13637932 the implementation for BP -> Customer should be done on BAdI Ci_CHANGE_LINK